# My OpenShift custom auto scaler haproxy_ctld only logs "no such file or directory"

Tags: ruby, openshift, haproxy, autoscaling

On an openshift PHP5.4 cartridge with embedded haproxy, I followed [the tuturial](https://blog.openshift.com/customizing-autoscale-functionality-in-openshift/) for putting a custom auto scaling algorithm in place. After I push my (executable) haproxy_ctld.rb code, it tells me to have restarted the haproxy_ctld successfully, however when I go via ssh to the shell of my app and type a command to the deamon it gives one or many (depending on the flags) times the message ": No such file or directory". When I look in the log file of haproxy_ctld it also only contains some entries of ": No such file or directory".

I did not change anything about the code. Only thing changes is that the file from [over here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openshift/origin-server/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-haproxy/usr/bin/haproxy_ctld.rb) is added as executable to the .openshift/action_hooks directory.

I also tried adding an info-logging statement as the first statement of each method in the file, to get a grip on what is happening. I would expect such log messages to appear in the log file e.g. after typing "haproxy_ctld -u" it should give me one of my added info-log messages, but no.

When removing the haproxy_ctld.rb file, typing haproxy_ctld --help gives me the help text like it should.

I ran out of ideas. Who has ANY idea what to do next, please help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out after creating a new app and following the tutorial all is well. Maybe the first time I skipped / overlooked the step of restarting the entire app as mentioned in the tutorial.